# How to insert Objects in object into variable

Tags: javascript, object

I have an objects inside parent object. Can I create an object in which there are these objects?

```
let a = {
  "11111": {"1": "test", "11": "test"},
  "22222": {"2": "test", "22": "test"}
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
  "1": "test", 
  "11": "test",
  "2": "test", 
  "22": "test",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reduce the object values by spreading them onto a new object.

```js
const
  a = {
    "11111": { "1": "test", "11": "test" },
    "22222": { "2": "test", "22": "test" }
  },
  b = Object.values(a).reduce((acc, obj) => ({ ...acc, ...obj }), {});
  
console.log(b);
```

If you want to be efficient, you can call `Object.assign` instead:

```js
const
  a = {
    "11111": { "1": "test", "11": "test" },
    "22222": { "2": "test", "22": "test" }
  },
  b = Object.values(a).reduce((acc, obj) => Object.assign(acc, obj), {});
  
console.log(b);
```